Wayfinding for indoor map without route network data
In general, to implement path planning, we need to create a road network beforehand and then use algorithms like Dijkstra for pathfinding. Meanwhile, the A* algorithm has been widely used in scenarios like game pathfinding and robot navigation, which bear similarities to indoor navigation. Therefore, I'm considering whether the A* algorithm can be applied to indoor path planning by providing obstacles such as walls and rooms, thus avoiding the need to create a road network, as manual road network creation can be costly.
However, based on my research, the A* algorithm seems to be suitable for grid networks composed of regular tiles (squares or hexagons), which can be understood as raster data. Yet, indoor map data, including walls and rooms, is often in vector format.
I've considered dividing the indoor map area into a grid of uniformly sized cells. If a cell intersects with an obstacle, it is considered an obstacle cell. Then, the A* algorithm can be applied. Nevertheless, choosing the grid size poses a challenge: there may be overlaps between the grid and obstacles, and the grid might cover entrances and exits, making pathfinding impossible.
Are there any other feasible solutions?

You could decompose your rooms and doors into a graph network

Thanks, any additional information like articles or something else?

Both algorithms works on both vectors and raster-like networks. Former just harder to make

I'd treat the doors as nodes and rooms as edges
